# How to rollup rows based on a given a combination in pandas Data frame?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame as follows.

```
df_add = pd.DataFrame({
    'unique_id':['a-1','a-2','a-3','a-4','a-5'],
    'doc_id':[100,101,102,103,104],
    'last_name':['Fernando','Fernando','Samba','Bhavik','Bhavik'],
    'first_name':['Reich','Reich','Anil','Reich','Reich'],
    'dob':['06-03-1900','06-03-1900','20-09-2020','09-16-2020','01-01-2021'],
    'health':['Yes','','Yes','','Yes']
})
```

[image]

We can see that there are two persons records are duplicated considering last_name and first_name as below.

1. Fernando Reich with same date of birth `06-03-1900’
2. Bhavik Reich with two different dates of births as ‘09-16-2020’ and ‘01-01-2021’

In case of duplicate combinations of last_name and first roll up of these rows should be done with semicolon separator as below for example:

**Case 1:**

a-1 and a-2 records are duplicated on last and first name, so it should be rolled up and recorded as a single.

Dob is considered as UNIQUE since it is existed in both of 2 records.

**a-1;a2 | 100;101 |Fernando |Reich |06-03-1900| Yes**

**Case 2:**

a-4 and a-5 records are duplicated on last and first name, it should be records as a single.
DOB’s are different for this person so they are separated with ;

**a-4;a-5 |103;104 |Bhavik |Reich |09-16-2020;01-01-201 |Yes**

Here the goal of this task is to remove duplicates and reduce the number of rows of a data frame, here is the expected output.

[image]

You can see that 5 rows are rolled up to 3 rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `GroupBy.agg`:

```
# function to aggregate as joined string without duplicates
# and maintaining original order
agg = lambda x: ';'.join(dict.fromkeys(map(str,x)))

out = (df_add
       .groupby(['last_name', 'first_name'], as_index=False)
       .agg({'unique_id': agg, 'doc_id': agg, 'dob': agg, 'health': 'max'})
      )
```

Output:

```
  last_name first_name unique_id   doc_id                    dob health
0    Bhavik      Reich   a-4;a-5  103;104  09-16-2020;01-01-2021    Yes
1  Fernando      Reich   a-1;a-2  100;101             06-03-1900    Yes
2     Samba       Anil       a-3      102             20-09-2020    Yes
```